# Change Status Bar color and text color of status bar in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

How we change a Color of Status Bar color in xamarin forms iOS.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can just hide the status bar at launch, but if you want the time to overlay on it you will need to head into your Info.plist file. You will find a Status Bar entry and you simply need to change it to Light Content and then it will display white text and icons. Or set this info in you info.plist.

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Set Navigation page BarTextcolor and BarBackgroundColor Property

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Pages.Security.Login()) { BarTextColor = Color.White , BarBackgroundColor= Color.Blue};
```

Comment: @Rahul If solved remember to mark it .